# HTML Wont center

Tags: html, css

Hello I want to try get this title to be in the centre. as shown here it just does not go to the centre and its really annoying me. 
screenshot of issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtZhX.jpg

If there is anyway in which you can also make this better that would be great. My goal is eventually to maker the centre box stretch 100% of the screen down

My main focus for this post is to make the text in the centre body box to basically have the title

## test

to be in the centre and then the

test

to be underneath a little bit in the centre so when I write it will be in the centre and when it reaches the end of the box it will make a new line/.

I also want it so the box is fixed to where it is and it doesn't ever move.

```css
* /*Main Navbar (at top) */ .navbar {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  border-bottom: 0.05px solid black;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #a0a0a0;
  border-bottom: 0.05px solid black;
  border: 0.05px solid black;
}

/*The body in the center of website */
.body-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.menu {
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: auto;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  text-decoration-color: black;
}

.body-container .menu .title {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 50%;
 
}
.body-container .body-text {

  text-align: center;
  margin-top:10%;
  

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/header.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/site.css">
  </head>

<body>
  <ul class="navbar">
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li style="float: right;  "><a href="#about">Login</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="body-container">
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="title">
        <h1>test</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="body-text">
        <p>test </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `padding-left:50%;` in `.body-container .menu .title` to center your headline. Furthermore, you used `display:flex`, this will occur that the subline doesn't get centered.

**Have a look into this Codepen.**
https://codepen.io/dmnktoe/pen/wOyxor

(Update: I would recommend you, not to use an absolute position for your element, since it isn't very responsive.)

Comment: you want it centered too?

Comment: Yh or even to the left would be great

Comment: Updated my answer. If you want the subline to be aligned on the left, switch "center" to left.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and worked:

```
.body-container .menu .title {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
.body-container .body-text {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 115px;
    left: 315px;
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Glad to help. Please verify the answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I always use margin: 0 auto; and it works almost all the times